# How to divide annual amount to months in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have an annual amount for each subscription with start_date

structure;

```
userid startDate(dd-mm-yyyy)     amount
1      01-10-2020                120
1      01-10-2021                240
2      01-08-2020                60
```

I want to divide annual amount to months equally.

Output table should be like;

```
userid startDate(dd-mm-yyyy)     amount
1      01-10-2020                10
1      01-11-2020                10
1      01-12-2020                10
1      01-01-2021                10
1      01-02-2021                10
1      01-03-2021                10
1      01-04-2021                10
1      01-05-2021                10
1      01-06-2021                10
1      01-07-2021                10
1      01-08-2021                10
1      01-09-2021                10

1      01-10-2021                20
1      01-11-2021                20
1      01-12-2020                20
1      01-01-2021                20
1      01-02-2021                20
1      01-03-2021                20
1      01-04-2021                20
1      01-05-2021                20
1      01-06-2021                20
1      01-07-2021                20
1      01-08-2021                20
1      01-09-2021                20

2      01-08-2020                5
2      01-09-2020                5
2      01-10-2020                5
2      01-11-2020                5
2      01-12-2020                5
2      01-01-2021                5
2      01-02-2021                5
2      01-03-2021                5
2      01-04-2021                5
2      01-05-2021                5
2      01-06-2021                5
2      01-07-2021                5
```

Where should I start, how can I achieve this on postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

```
select userid
      ,generate_series(startdate, startDate + interval '11 month', '1 month')
      ,amount/12
from   t
```

| userid | generate_series | ?column? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 1 | 2020-11-01 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 1 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 1 | 2021-11-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 1 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 1 | 2022-05-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 1 | 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 1 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 1 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 1 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | 20 |
| 2 | 2020-08-01 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 2020-11-01 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 5 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bCupOtMG)

Comment: thank you DannySlor, but how is it possible without generate_series? it seems my version of postgreSQL doesn't support it

Comment: Generate_Series for dates/timestamps was introduced in v8.4 (EOL 8 years ago). So you either have an even older version or you have an error in the query. I'm betting on the latter. Please post, as update to your question,  the exact query and the exact complete error message. Post as text, **not an  image**.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, you may try a recursive query as the following:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS
  (
    SELECT userid, startDate, amount/12 AS amount, 1 AS cn
    FROM table_name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT userid, startDate + interval '1 month', amount, cn+1
    FROM CTE WHERE cn+1 <= 12
  )
SELECT userid, startDate, amount FROM CTE
ORDER BY userid, startDate, cn
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hl9rbWeA).